# Match entire string with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am validating a UK postcode using the regex pattern [supplied by the British government](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/488478/Bulk_Data_Transfer_-_additional_validation_valid_from_12_November_2015.pdf). My test currently looks like this:

```
const postcodeRegex = /^([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([AZa-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z]))))[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})$/g;

console.log(postcodeRegex.test('s75ed')); // returns true
console.log(postcodeRegex.test('s75ed555555')); // returns false
console.log(postcodeRegex.test('555555s75ed')); // returns true
```

The first 2 console logs are correct, but I expected the 3rd to return false. The test returns true when the pattern is matched at the end of the string, but this allows any jibberish at the start of the string, meaning overall the entire string is an invalid postcode.

How do I strictly match the pattern to the entire string?

Comment: Is this pattern copied directly from the British government? If so, I'm surprised they haven't properly tested this on their own. Seems to have several flaws :o)

Comment: @agrm Yes direct from a document published on the .gov website. Unbelievable I know but that's the sort of thing government does.

Comment: @agrm I added a link to the PDF.

Comment: Technically, @coop, you are verifying that a string meets the specification of a postcode, not validating it. To validate it, I would suggest using an online api such as postcodes.io

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Prime Minister personally approved this regex. Either way, it's definitely not the fault of the 99% of software developers who can't write a simple regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex has this shape: `^A|B$`.
It seems you didn't expect that this will match `Agibberish` and `gibberishB`, and you're actually looking for `^(A|B)$`.
Written this way,
it will only match `A` or `B`,
it will not match `Agibberish` and `gibberishB`.

Btw this part of the regex looks like a bug: `[AZa-z]`.
You probably meant `[A-Za-z]`.

And in fact all alphabetic letters in the regex appear in both upper- and lowercase forms. So you could simplify by quite bit if you add the `i` flag and eliminate one of the cases:

```
const postcodeRegex = /^((gir 0a{2})|((([a-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([a-z][a-hj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([a-z][0-9][a-z])|([a-z][a-hj-y][0-9]?[a-z]))))[0-9][a-z]{2}))$/gi;
```

Comment: Great, this solves more problems than I thought existed. Trust the government to supply an incorrect pattern for this.

Comment: Even the corrected regex doesn't fully validate a postcode. Some letters, such as Q, cannot appear in the first position. The letter I is never used. Only certain combinations are valid, The district G in the first position on its own is fine, but only GL, GU and GY are valid with second letters. And so on.

Answer (score 2):

If we add some whitespace and indentation, your regex looks like this:

```
   ^([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})
|
   ((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([AZa-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z]))))[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})$
```

I.e. only the first alternative is anchored to the beginning of the string (`^`), and only the second alternative is anchored to the end of the string (`$`).

You can wrap the whole thing in a (non-capturing) group instead:

```
^(?:...|...)$
```

Comment: Brilliant, the new grouping seems to solve the problem. I'm surprised the British government publicly share an incorrect regex pattern for this... Wait a minute, I'm not surprised at all.